# r binding data frames in different combinations in for loop

Tags: r

I have generated 10 data frames S1 to S10. Now I want to create 10 more data frames T1 to T10 using S1 to S10 in different combinations. Each T Sets will have 9 of the S Sets.

Example,

```
T1 = rbind(S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10)   # If T1 is the set, S1 should not be there.    
.  
.  
.   
T10 = rbind(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9)  # T10 not there.
```

How Can I generate T1 to T10 using for loop, assuming S1 to S10 data frames is provided with equal number of columns and headers are same through out S1 to S10.

Any help is highly appreciated. If not for loop, suggest any other function.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way

```
S1 <- data.frame(x=1)
S2 <- data.frame(x=2)
S3 <- data.frame(x=3)

lst <- mget(grep("S\\d+", ls(), value = TRUE))
idx <- combn(1:length(lst), length(lst)-1)[, length(lst):1]
res <- apply(idx, 2, function(x) {
  do.call(rbind, lst[x])
})
names(res) <- paste0("T", 1:length(lst))
list2env(res, .GlobalEnv)
```

`apply` uses a loop under the hood.